# Unable to join or convert in the object menu even though I've selected all the curves

Tags: edit-mode, selection-tools

[image]

I am new to Blender. I know that if I select one curve it would be " active selected" and I can go into the edit mode or join/convert, but how to make all the curves become active selected? I want to convert the curves to mesh, the menu "join" and " convert" is greyed out. and I checked that there's no camera or lighting selected.

Answer (score 1):

The way you were doing it, all your curves were selected but none of them was active. So hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click one of the curves. This will make the curve active, while selection remains because of <kbd>Shift</kbd>

Comment: Thank you so much for replying me! I tried hold shift and click but it only make one curve active, is there any way to make the whole object active? Because I want convert it to mesh in the next step.

Comment: Once you have that curve active, you can join them all into a single curve with Ctrl-J and then convert that to a mesh.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I joined them into a single curve but the shape distorted.. I googled it and the step is exactly the same as you said but I feel like I did something wrong so it turned out distorted... I will try again from the beginning